# Connecting a 12c oracle database failed using pyspark 3.2.0 ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: []

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, plsql, oracle12c

I made my standalone pyspark cluster. When I need to create a DataFrame the followin command:

```
    df_ora=spark.read.format('jdbc')\
        .option('url',credenciales.get('PRD')[0]['URL'])\
        .option('driver', 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')\
        .option('dbtable',"("+query2+") query")\
        .option('inferSchema', False)\
        .option('user', credenciales.get('PRD')[0]['USER'])\
        .option('password',credenciales.get('PRD')[0]['PASSWORD'])\
        .load()
```

And the db response with the Error Msg = ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []. And that's one Oracle error due to the subquery the spark is making to infer the schema (…. where 1=0), eventhought the I explicitily write InferSchema False, when i use a query with joins (query 2) or if i use the command:

```
    df_ora=spark.read.format('jdbc')\
        .option('url',credenciales.get('PRD')[0]['URL'])\
        .option('driver', 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')\
        .option('query',query2)\
        .option('inferSchema', False)\
        .option('user', credenciales.get('PRD')[0]['USER'])\
        .option('password',credenciales.get('PRD')[0]['PASSWORD'])\
        .load()
```

still the same error. I copied and pasted the same subquery of spark is making into my PLSQL IDE the that confirmed the the subquery of spark is making the error. If I use a single table o if the joins query ends with 'order by' it Works.

Someone that strunggled the same error?.

Of course i not the DBA to create a view and use it. Or create a single dataframe for each table to make the joins inside the Python scripts is not an option or practical.

Comment: ORA-00600 is usually *bad news* as it represents Oracle **bug**. Check My Oracle Support; maybe there's a solution, workaround or patch available. Otherwise, hope that someone else knows what to do, will see your question and assist. Or - as most of us regularly do - Google for it.

Comment: If there isn't a known answer to the specific ORA-00600 error in the My Oracle Support knowledge base (which happens frequently) you (or more likely your DBA) will have to open a service request with Oracle Support to have the bug investigated and resolved.

Comment: I made my own reserch and test (removing part of the query and testing again and over again) i found out the if your query has a select subquery that has a fetch one 1 row and then add this *query with select * from (*query) subquery_spark where 1=0 as spark.read does it throws this error ORA-00600. all this test I use my PLSQL IDE to confirm that apache-spark is not part of the issue.